# Discord.py How to fix looping message (on_message)

Tags: events, discord, discord.py, bots

Anybody can help me with code i programmed simple event but not working bot ignores one part of the code and the next part works, but when the bot send a message, bot spamming this message, thx for help.

````
@bot.event
async def on_message(ctx):

    if ctx.content.startswith("-") or ctx.content.startswith("+") :
      await bot.process_commands(ctx)

    if ctx.channel.category.id == 909114663868973106 or ctx.channel.category.id == 838806063418966057 or ctx.channel.category.id == 909114621980454962:
    
      admin1 = ctx.guild.get_member(640961296665149440)
      admin2 = ctx.guild.get_member(708704382828544071)
      admin3 = ctx.guild.get_member(838159011605512202)
      admin4 = ctx.guild.get_member(895743036338884689)

      if admin1.status == discord.Status.offline and admin2.status == discord.Status.offline and admin3.status == discord.Status.offline and admin4.status == discord.Status.offline :
        await ctx.add_reaction('⏳')
        await ctx.channel.send("Wait for support!") 

    
    elif ctx.mentions:
      if ctx.channel.category.id == 909114663868973106 or ctx.channel.category.id == 838806063418966057 or ctx.channel.category.id == 909114621980454962:
      
        if ctx.author.guild_permissions.administrator:
          print(ctx.author.status)
          
          user2 = ctx.mentions[0].id
          user = await ctx.guild.query_members(user_ids=user2) 
          user = user[0]
          
          await ctx.add_reaction('✅')

          embed=discord.Embed(color=0xe5f476)
          embed.add_field(name="You have been mentioned by an administrator!!", value=f"You have been mentioned by an administrator in **{ctx.channel.mention}** channel.\nMention usually is for an update in ur ticket, most likely something important!\nCheck the server for more information about this staff mention.\n", inline=False)
          embed.set_footer(text=f"⭐ Use -tagnotif on #{ctx.channel.name} for stopping this messages. ⭐")
          await user.send(embed=embed) 
          await bot.process_commands(ctx)```
````

Comment: Try to add `if ctx.author == ctx.guild.me: return` in the begging of the event.

Comment: Yea working, thx so much